# scipy differential evolution with multiprocessing inside of a for loop

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, multiprocessing

code is quite simple and it doesn't really matter what it is I think.  Could be wrong, idk I'm not the best at this.
I'm trying to get scipy's differential evolution function work with multiprocessing while inside a for loop.  I've tried a couple of methods to get it to work, but I can't figure it out.  It seems to always require the if **name** == '**main**': piece for forking reasons (I don't really know what that means, I've tried to read about it online and I still don't get it).  However, because of the if **name** == '**main**':, it ends up running the entire code many many times over and I'm not sure why.  I think it has to do with thinking that everything with less indentation than the if **name** == '**main**': begins is global and needs to be run from the start because all my other global functions start running multiple times over in a recursive loop I think.  idk, I can share more if you think it will be helpful.

```
def voldiscovery(): 
    alpha = .25 
    currentvol = currentvolcalc(hvwindow)
    for y in range (16, len(logreturns)):

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            x = currentvol[15:y]
            z = estimates[y]
    
            args = (x, z)
            bounds = [(.01, .5)]
                sol1 = differential_evolution(alphaoptimizer, strategy='best1exp', maxiter=3000,              init='latinhypercube', bounds=bounds, updating='deferred', workers=-1, args=args)
```

I tried foregoing the if **name** == '**main**': , that doesn't work.  I tried putting in another function and calling that function in for loop.  That absolutely didn't work.

I was hoping that for each iteration of the for loop, it would run the optimization once (on all cores), and then continue on it's merry way to the next bit of code after the for loop has concluded.

Comment: Have you got it working without parallelisation first?

Comment: yup, it runs fine when workers =1

Comment: Don't add unnecessary text like "code is quite simple and it doesn't really matter what it is I think. Could be wrong, idk I'm not the best at this.". Make your questions as easy to read as possible for others please.

Answer (score 0):

working with multiprocessing requires your code to be **importable** without side-effects.

specifically, you should define code as follows:

```py
import multiprocessing
import my_modules

def function1():
    ...

def function2():
    ...

def main():
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

the above module can be imported without triggering the execution of your application, because the other processes **do** import your module if they are started using `spawn` (which basically means you are using windows/macOS, or you set the start method to spawn on linux)

Comment: okay, so all 3 of my braincells are trying hard to figure this out.  I put the if __name__ == "__main__":  all the way out and nested everything inside it and it works!.... kinda lololol.  it runs over 21x slower and I think it has to do with what you were talking about.  I have a lot of global variables and processes like importing csvs, calculations to clean the data, etc., and I think it constantly keeps running the global stuff.  Do you think this is the case?  Any advice?

Comment: @ChandlerTso yes, you shouldn't put them in the global scope, my advice is to structure your code as stated in the answer .... imports, then function definitions, then the guarded main code.